# android: getting the time taken by the server to respond

Tags: android, response

I need to get the time taken by a server to respond when some request is send to the server in android.
How shall i do this.
CAn anyone help me over this.?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//
long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

// some code here, eg: request remote server

long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
long elapse = t2 - t1;
//
```